# I set new state but it remains unchanged in next line function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have piece of a code that I don't entirely understand why it acts like that.

`const handleLoadMore = () => { setPageNumber(pageNumber+1); fetchData(pageNumber); };`

State `pageNumber` remains same as I didn't change the state. Outside of the `handleLoadMore` function increments. I kind of understand that it won't increment function body. So, is there anyway to tell `fetchData(pageNumber)` to wait for state to update.

I tried to find on google how to solve this kind of a problem. I tried setTimeout function but it didn't help.

Comment: Use a `useEffect` hook to call a function when a state changes.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I appreciate your answer but there is another parameter in fetchData call that I don't want to run useEffect and if I exclude it inside useEffect lint says that I am missing dependency.

Comment: @SKImperator Why don't you want to run it when that other parameter changes?

Comment: @caTS because I have another useEffect function that executes on that parameter change. And if I include it app doesn't behave as wanted.

Comment: Maybe you need a [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)?

Comment: Include more relevant code. The obvious answer is `useEffect`, but if there are more parameters to consider, then they should be added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = React.useState(0);

const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setPageNumber(number => number + 1);
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(pageNumber);
},[pageNumber])
```

Answer (score 0):

You state setter function is happening asynchronously (this is by default with React), meaning it is not executed until the call stack is clear, so *after* your `fetchData` call has been made.

Presumably, the `handleLoadMore` function is event-based, like a button `onClick`.

So instead, pass the `pageNumber + 1` to the `fetchData` function directly.  No need for `useEffect`.

```js
const handleLoadMore = () => {
  setPageNumber(previousNum => previousNum + 1)
  fetchData(pageNumber + 1)
}
```

**Important Side-note**

When updating state with a reference to itself, it is best practice to use the function argument syntax, to ensure you are not updating based on a stale reference to the state.